# The open unit ball minus an half-open interval $[0,1)$ is homeomorphic to the open ball

Tags: general-topology

Let $\mathbb{B}^2$ be the open unit ball in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Then how can we show that the set $\mathbb{B}^2 \backslash \{(x,0): 0 \le x < 1\}$ is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{B}^2$?

Comment: I don't know if this sheds any light but the open unit ball without the half open interval is like pac man slightly closing his mouth. If we open that mouth, it becomes a semicircle without its boundary, which is clearly homeomorphic to the open unit ball.

Answer (score 1):

The open unit disk $\Bbb B^2$ is homeomorphic to the open half-disk $\Bbb D^2:=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb B^2\,:\, x>0\}$. Now, notice that the map $(x,y)\mapsto (x^2-y^2,2xy)$ is a homeomorphism from $\Bbb D^2$ onto your set, with inverse $$(x,y)\mapsto\left(\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}+x}2},\,\operatorname{sign}(y)\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{x^2+y^2}-x}2}\right)$$

(why is this inverse continuous, by the way?)

Comment: What happens for $y=0$ in the inverse map? And how did you come up with such a map? I don't get the intuition.

Comment: $\operatorname{sign}(0)=0$. The idea comes from $\Bbb C$.

Comment: A simpler way to define $f : \mathbb D^2  \to \mathbb{B}^2 \backslash \{(x,0): 0 \le x < 1\}$ is to use complex numbers: $f(z) = z^2$.

Comment: @nomadicmathematician As Paul said: it's just the squaring map on $\Bbb C$: square the length and double the argument (= the angle with the positive $x$-axis).